# Expire documents in Cloudant

Tags: cloudant

Is there any way to expire documents from the database? For example set a time of 10 hours and all documents aged 10hours+ are deleted from the database.

Our data only makes sense during the day, anything older is useless and can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In short no. What you can do however is build it into your application logic, but that is going to cause overheads which may be detrimental to your application's performance.